# Multi generational ship FAQ

Tags: discussion

Recently I got into multi generational ships topic and I feel that I am not only interested in ideas how we could travel to another solar system at speeds slower than lightspeed

Purpose of this meta post is to gather all multi generational ship posts on one place. I will start with my additions and mark the answer as Community Wiki.

Please feel free adding other posts

Comment: This is *exactly* what tagging is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, stop. I realized there is tag [generation-ships](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generation-ships) which does exactly the thing I need to do.

Which means I tagged my own questions appropriately and recommend others to apply the same approach when talking about multi generation ships

Answer (score 2):

The current "series" meta questions for the most part are actually a series (i.e. how the realistic worlds one started out) where the questions all reference each other. Having a single meta post that they can all link to rather than linking to each other allows those questions to be organised better.

Grouping questions by categories as you already noted is better off done using tags.

The "anatomically correct" series is more borderline as to whether the meta post is relevant. The difference there though is both that there was no clear tag that applied to relevant questions and only those questions and there were a considerable number of questions.

Comment: Yep. I noticed that when I started to put together the links below. At least I will be able to accept my own answer :D